# result totally different using chrome and firefox 10.2

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I create this text effect:

```
.inset-text
{
    background-color: #666666;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0 3px 3px;          
}

<p class="inset-text">Some Text</p>
```

Unfortunately If you try to run this example using Firefox you see a gray rectangle instead in Chrome everything works well.How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `background-clip` can take the value `text`? In either [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp) or the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip) I don't see this listed. By the way, Firefox now accepts just `background-clip` too.

Comment: yeah...I realize background-clip:text isn't supported by Mozilla and IE.only browsers that uses web-kit

Answer (score 1):

```
background-clip: text;
```

Is only supported in webkit-based browsers right now (Chrome and Safari).  It's non-standard so it's hard to say if the text attribute will ever become supported in the other browsers (Firefox, Opera, and Internet Explorer).  What effect are you trying to accomplish?  I can probably give you a good alternative without using it.